# How can I get data from @DBRef document using @Query -> Spring data mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need help to get the data from another document I have the following class.

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "tmVersion")
public class TmVersion {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String cVrVersionId;

    @DBRef
    private TaApplicationVersion taApplicationVersion;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "taApplicationVersion")
public class TaApplicationVersion {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String dVrAppName;

    private String dVrAppCode;

}
```

This is my repository in which I map what I want to be shown but in taApplicationVersion I need to show all this object also how is it done?

```
@Query(value="{}", fields="{'cVrVersionId': 1, 'taApplicationVersion.dVrAppName': 2, 
'dVrVersionNumber': 3}") 
Page<TmVersion> getAllVersionWithOutFile(Pageable pageable)
```

Comment: It is not clear as to what you want. Can you give an example input and output

Comment: In my consultation I want to obtain
id, dVrAppName, dVrAppCode of the document TaApplicationVersion plus the fields of the tmVersion table

Comment: So you need all the fields(including subfields) of TmVersion class? are u gettig any error with the query you have above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to mention here.

1. If you want this kind of join between tables, then you need to rethink your choice of Mongodb as database. No Sql Databases thrive on the fact that there is very less coupling between tables(collections). So if you are using `@DBRef`, it negates that. Mongodb themselves do not recommend using `@DBRef`.
2. This cannot be achieved with the method like you have in the repository. You need to use Projections. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.binding) is the documentation for that.
   Create a Porjection interface like this. Here you can control which fields you need to include in the Main class(TmVersion)

   ```
   @ProjectedPayload
   public interface TmVersionProjection {

     @Value("#{@taApplicationVersionRepository.findById(target.taApplicationVersion.id)}")
     public TaApplicationVersion getTaApplicationVersion();
     public String getId();
     public String getcVrVersionId();
   }
   ```

Change the TmVersionRepository like this

```
public interface TmVersionRepository extends MongoRepository<TmVersion, String> {

    @Query(value="{}")
    Page<TmVersionProjection> getAllVersionWithOutFile(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Create a new Repository for TaApplicationVersion. You can add `@Query` on top of this method and control which fields from subclass needs to be returned.

```
public interface TaApplicationVersionRepository extends MongoRepository<TaApplicationVersion, String> {
      TaApplicationVersion findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: What happens is that I am migrating a bd sql server to mongodb and I would like to know how to work it correctly since I have some related tables and I don't know how to work it in mongodb. Could you give me an example to guide me or information thanks.